# WCF and method accepting Stream

Tags: c#, wcf

I have WCF:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface Receiver {

    [OperationContract, WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile")]
    void UploadFile(Stream fileContents);
}
```

And UploadFile method save file on hard drive then sending it to other two services. It is hosted on IIS 7 Windows Server 2008. So on my other background project i have added service reverence to that Receiver service and when I tried:

```
FileStream f = new FileStream(myString, FileMode.Open);
ReceiverServiceReference.IReceiverProcess r = new ReceivererviceReference.ReceiverProcessClient();
  try
  {
      r.UploadFile(f);
      f.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
```

I get at `r.UploadFile(f)`:

> There was no endpoint listening at "address" that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

and InnerException:

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

What I know:

the two services that receiver is passing fille are working right

receiver service is accessible, I can access it by web browser

As it goes for `WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile")` we have closed soft that is sending stream by "address"/UploadFile and it is working right.

Comment: Have you checked what IP address and port `r` is trying to connect to?

Comment: Yes, no problems with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem whas in project settings:

[image]

I have renamed service from ReceiverService.svc to ReceiverProcess.svc but in Web > Start Action > Specyific Page whas still ReceiverService.svc, changing it to ReceiverProcess.svc did the trick :)

Hope this can help someone.